Casting Pointer array from one type to another
Why is the following program not working?
void test(int*[]);
int main()
{
    char *a[2];
    test((int*[])a);
    
    return 0;
}

void test(int* c[]){

}

It shows

error cast to incomplete type 'int*[]' test((int*[])a)

The problem can be fixed by using:
test((int**)a);

But what is wrong with the previous code?
Edit: In the function prototype declaration, the same thing is used inside the parenthesis as the cast.

(int*[])

So why is that not an incomplete type?

int * and char * are different types. The compiler diagnoses this. If you attempt to hide the error with a cast, the behaviour at runtime is undefined

That's not correct. The following program runs: void test(int*);
int main()
{
char* a;
test(a);
return 0;

}
void test(int* c){
}

That program is ill-formed and must generate a diagnostic. Also it is fundamentally different to this one.  There you attempt to convert char * to int * ; in this question you attempt to reinterpret char * as int *

I'm not sure casting whole array at once is correct, try to cast each member separately.

"what is wrong with the previous code?" --> int*[] is an incomplete type, not suitable for casting.

That's not correct. The following program runs - That's meaningless. The fact that code compiles and runs does not mean it's correct - it just means that the syntax works. You can compile and run horrible code that contains logic errors and memory overwrites, and even get lucky and have it work for a minute or an hour or a week or a year. That doesn't change the fact that it;'s wrong.

Sure. But where is the syntax error? That's what I wanted to know. In the function prototype declaration above, I used the same thing as the cast (int*[]). So why is that not an incomplete type?

In a function parameter list, array types (at top level) are adjusted to pointer types

@Cryogen There is no syntax error, there is a constraint error meaning that you are breaking mandatory rules of the C language.

Treating an array of char as an array of int is also a strict aliasing violation and invokes undefined behavior on its own, and it can also invoke undefined behavior if int has a stricter alignment requirement than char.

The problem is that int *[] is an incomplete type which cannot be instantiated.
In the function declaration, int *[] is exactly equivalent to int ** since the actual argument passed to the function will be a "pointer to pointer to int" in either case. Therefore, in the context of the function declaration, int *[] actually refers to a complete type (pointer to pointer to int).
In the cast, however, (int *[])a tells the compiler to create a temporary of type int *[] and that is not allowed since it is an incomplete type.
While we cannot have values of incomplete type, we can have pointers to such values, so the following compiles (just for the sake of the example; this is not a recommended construct) - a typedef is used for clearer notation:
typedef int * incompleteIntArray[];

void test(int*[]);
int main()
{
    char *a[2];
    test(*(incompleteIntArray *)&a);
}

The point here is that while incompleteIntArray (aka int *[]) is an incomplete type, a pointer to this type is not. Therefore, a pointer &a to char *[2] can be cast to a pointer to int *[] and we may dereference this to create the function argument. However, this only works because arrays are always passed by reference, so the actual argument is a pointer, not an instance of int *[].

This is not the problem. The problem is that casts of array type are not allowed.

@Lundin I think that is a matter of perspective. The OP compiler message is quite clear, but my compiler also complains about casting an array type as you say. Regardless of the issue with casting an array type, there is the incomplete type problem which I chose to focus on.

C simply does not allow casts of array type. Likely for the same reason as it does not allow assignment of array types. It's just how the language is specified.
C17 6.5.4 Cast operators:

Constraints
Unless the type name specifies a void type, the type name shall specify atomic, qualified, or unqualified scalar type, and the operand shall have scalar type.

Scalar meaning "single variable", as opposed to "aggregate" which is arrays or structs. So casting a struct to a different struct type isn't allowed either.
In some situations you could cast a pointer to array or pointer to struct into a pointer to a different array or struct, but that's almost always incorrect practice as well and in many cases invokes undefined behavior.
The reason why (int**)a compiles is because an array parameter in a function always gets implicitly adjusted to a pointer to its first element. So in case of void test(int*[]);, that's 100% equivalent to void test(int**); because the first element is an int* and a pointer to one would be int**.
But just because your code compiles doesn't mean it's correct. C allows all manner of wild and crazy pointer conversions, but casting from a character pointer-to-pointer to an int pointer-to-pointer still enforces an invalid conversion. Because these types are not compatible and dereferening the resulting pointer will result in undefined behavior bugs.
The specific warning about int*[] being an incomplete type is less relevant here, because the code is wildly incorrect either way. An array with no dimension specified is an incomplete type. In case of the function it doesn't matter, since the array will get adjusted anyway as previously mentioned. But elsewhere in the code it probably does not make sense to create an instance of incomplete array type, should C even allow it. Which it doesn't, since casts on array types are invalid.
